# Is there a term for functions which are greater than a bound?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, terminology

A function $f(x)$ is called bounded if $|f(x)|\leq M$ for some $M$.

How about a function $|f(x)|>M$ for all $x$ (for some $M$)? Is there any special terminology for it?

Thanks.

Comment: Bounded from below?

Comment: @rah4927 I thought bounded from below means it has a lower bound? $f(x)$ could go to negative infinity.

Comment: No, there is not special terminology for that.

Comment: @yoyostein yeah sorry I missed the modulus. I suppose you could say the function $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is bounded, but it might just be easier to say  $|f(x)|>M$ .